# Get value from select tag on view send to controller in var ruby and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

please can help me.

I am trying to get the values ​​of the "value" fields from my select_tag in rails and send it to the controller to use in variables to execute some commands, could help me follow my code.

**This my view with 2 select_tags this is firsts select_tag one choice option and, go to second below**

```
<select id="channel" name="channel"><option value="747">0800 0</option>
<option value="1750"> 0800 3</option>
<option value="1845"> 0800 1</option>
<option value="1839">0800 4</option>
<option value="1831">0800 5</option>
<option value="1326">08000 6</option>
<option value="1848">08000 7</option>
<option value="582">08000 8</option>
<option value="182">08000 9</option>
<option value="1838">0800 10</option></select>
```

**This my view with the second select_tag choice one option with first select_tag.**

```
<select id="opts" name="opts"><option value="578">opt 0</option>
<option value="470">opt 1</option>
<option value="577">opt 2</option>
<option value="600">opt 3</option>
<option value="539">opt 4</option></select>
```

i'm trying to get the values ​​of the two select_tags on my controller i'm studying rails and ruby ​​and i still couldn't do it could help me with my code

could show me how to receive these values ​​in the controller I'm looking for examples

Comment: please share the controller's & view's code so that we can assist you,
in the mean while you can read this from the manual https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag#1185-How-to-submit-current-url

Comment: my controller:  #options
    @opts = Machines.find(:all, :conditions => ["opts_id = ? AND machines_type_id = 3", @clients.id])

Comment: What's the issue? Aren't the values present in `params[:channel]` and `params[:opts]` on form submit?

Comment: yes, i want send this params to controller opts and channel i using two params selecteds to populate array var .. with a button <%= button_to "Change Channel", { :action => "change_channel" },:confirm => "Want confirm change?" %>

Comment: Did you wrap it in a `form` ?

Comment: no only button with action and select_tags

Comment: A specific reason why you did not wrap it in a form? Because that is exactly what a form is for. Or do you want to use javascript?

Comment: i dont know create forms in rails i find on api rails doc to understand and trying examples

Comment: You could take a look at the Rails guide [Action View Form Helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) which offers examples and detailed explanations.